# Python function parameters for Pool.map

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

```
 from multiprocessing import Pool
 from urllib.request import urlretrieve     
 tmp= Pool(4).map(urlretrieve, urls)
```

How can i specifiy the filename for urlretrieve in that case?

Comment: you have already passed `urls` argument. make your question to be more clear

Comment: Yeah but `urls` is used as `url` in urlretrieve. I want to also specify the filename

Comment: again, update your question with all input filenames that need to be requested, avoid confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify multiple arguments and you don't want to have to unpack them in the function `urlretrieve` (which you don't have access too) then perhaps you can try using the `starmap`.  Example, here we are passing in both the `url` and the `filename`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com"]
filenames = ["google.html", "yahoo.html"]
results = Pool(2).starmap(urlretrieve, zip(urls, filenames))
```